# Duality in algebraic de Rham cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, homology-cohomology, duality-theorems

I am trying to prove that the following is a short exact sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow H^0(X,\Omega_X) \rightarrow H^1_{\text {dR}}(X/k) \rightarrow H^1(X,\mathcal O_X) \rightarrow 0,
$$
where $k$ is an algebraically closed field and $X$ is a smooth projective curve.

Using Cech cohomology I have derived the long exact sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow H^0_{\text{dR}}(X/k) \rightarrow H^0(X,\mathcal O_X) \rightarrow H^0(X,\Omega_x) \rightarrow H^1_{\text{dR}}(X/k) \rightarrow H^1(X,\mathcal O_X) \rightarrow H^1(X,\Omega_X) \rightarrow H^2_{\text{dR}}(X/k) \rightarrow 0
$$
and if I can show the first and last (non-trivial) maps are isomorphisms I am done.

I can show the injectivity of the short exact sequence anyway, but the surjectivity is eluding me.

Any help would be useful, but in particular I thought there may be some duality theorem. Since $H^1(X,\Omega_X) = k$ then all I need to do is show $H^2_{\text {dR}} (X/k) \neq 0$ and I will be done.

Since I know that $H^0_{\text {dR}}(X/k)$ is non-zero I thought a duality theorem may complete this, but I can only find analytic duality theorems, and certainly none that clearly hold in positive characteristic.

Comment: "Since $H^1(X,O_X)=k \ldots$" Not true; did you mean to have an $\Omega$ there instead?

Comment: Yep, thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ is projective, a global function is a constant, so it's killed by $d$, which gives the injectivity of the first map.

For the surjectivity of the second, note that a projective curve can always be covered by *two* open affines (since a point is ample by Riemann-Roch). Write down the Cech complex with respect to a double cover (i.e. resolve $\mathcal{O}$ and $\Omega$ separately, then take the total complex), and you will get surjectivity directly.

As far as duality is concerned, see Tate's (still very readable) paper on residues for an algebraic computation. The one-line summary is: you can define residues formally as coefficients of $a_{-1}$ in Laurent expansions without actually doing any complex analysis, and this recovers classical duality theory for algebraic curves. Note however that this doesn't work in characteristic $p$, and in general algebraic de Rham cohomology is broken in characteristic $p$.

Comment: Thank you. Can I check, with reference to the paper by Tate, are you referring to "Residues of differential on curves"? If so, does this not pertain to Serre duality, rather than a duality of algebraic de Rham cohomology?

I was hoping I could use this as a shortcut to avoid the computation you described, but if doing it directly is the only way then I guess that will have to do :)

Comment: that's right -- he doesn't directly mention adrC in the paper, instead, he interprets serre duality in terms of residues, using the Tate complex of sheaves (which I will descirbe in a second) -- but thepoint is that you can use this complex, rather than the Cech complex, to compute adRC and recover duality for curves

Comment: in general adRC does satisfy a poincare duality statement (i.e. not just for curves) and it doesn't use tate's paper, so maybe that reference was misleading. The Tate complex goes 0 ---> sheaf of regular functions ---> constant sheaf of meromorphic functions ---> the sheaf that eats U and gives the direct sum over P in U of formal Laurent expansions of meromorphic functions at P mod formal Taylor expansions of holomorphic functions at P ---> 0

Comment: this complex is obviously a flasque resolution. you can do the same thing with Omega (replace meromorphic functions with meromorphic 1-forms and sum K_p/O_p with sum Omega_{K_p}/Omega_{O_P}.) these resolutions are compatible, and that will gives you a double complex to compute adRC with.

Comment: note that capitalizations of adRC in the preceding comments are motivated more by when I happen to be holding the shift key than by logic :)

Comment: Thanks very much for the comments. For some reason I really am struggling to show it directly, but hopefully if I stare for long enough it will be clear to me. Thank you for the comments and help :)

Comment: did this work out ? I forgot about it ! I did this by hand a few years ago because I was stuck on something similar, so I can try to dig up those notes if you want the details.

Comment: I still can't quite get the surjectivity directly. I was trying Cech cohomology to start with and I got to the point where I need to show that if $f$ is regular on $U_1 \cap U_2$ then there are differentials $\omega_i$ regular on $U_i$ such that $df = \omega_1 - \omega_0$. I may be able to do this over $\mathbb C$, but I can't see why this is true in general.

Comment: Any help would be great, I was about to post another questions specifically asking this. Interestingly, it seems like exactly the same reason that I can't show directly that $H^2_{\text{dR}}(X) \cong k$.

Comment: Definitely go ahead and post that question as I may be a while !

Comment: Using the resolution described above in these comments, you are trying to show that if I give you a finite set of points, and a Laurent expansion of a 1-form at each point, such that the sum of the residues is 0, then there is a global form equal to your laurent expansion at each of the given points, and holomorphic elsewhere. This (hopefully) follows from Riemann-Roch, which, notwithstanding my sloppy use of the words holomorphic and meromorphic, works over any $k$. Let me know if you finish this proof ! You also may be able to Riemann-Roch the proof directly with your Cech description

Comment: Oh, but you already have an upper bound on the dimension at 1, so actually, you are done (since by the residue theorem a class of the form (P, t^{-1}dt) in the description of H^2 above CAN'T be trivial). This is probably the argument from a few years ago I was referring to. If my description of H^2 doesn't make sense I can type out a new answer - let me know.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply: I have asked the question separately, which I have linked to at the end. I almost follow your reasoning, but the global form I find may or may not be closed (i.e. df), and I don't see why R-R would give me that part.